# The automorphism scheme of a fibered surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, schemes, representable-functor, fibre-product

Let $f:S \to B$ be a genus $g$ fibration
($B$ is a smooth projective curve, $S$ a smooth projective surface and the general fiber $F_b$ of $f$ is of genus $g \ge 2$). I would like to ask some references on the scheme $X \to B$ representing the functor $(Sch/B)^{opp} \to Sets$ mapping $C \to B$ to $Isom_C(S\times_B C,S \times_B C)$. (It should be representable as the subfunctor of a suitable Hilbert Scheme).

In particular I am looking for a result on the finiteness of $X \to B$ and on the structure of $X_b$  (in particular do we have $X_b=Aut(F_b)$? I think yes or at least this is not obviously false to me since $Hom_B(F_b,X)=Hom_B(F_b,Aut(F_b))=Aut(F_b)=Isom_{F_b}(S \times_B F_b,S \times_B F_b)$).

I need this to prove the following fact: if the general fiber has automorphism group $Aut(F_b)=\mathbb{Z}_n$ then up to base change (to a smooth projective curve $B' \to B$) we have $\mathbb{Z}_n \subset Aut_{B'}(S)$. If I didn't make mistakes, this should follow by taking $B'$ minimal over the connected components of $X$ and the compatibility of the the $Isom$-scheme with base change.
If needed somewhere I may suppose to work over $\mathbb{C}$ and to have stable fibers (this seems necessary in order to have $X \to B$ finite, as suggested in the comment)

Thank you in advance

Comment: At least over the open subset $U \subset B$ where the fibers of $f$ are smooth, we have a family of smooth proper genus $g$ curves. It is `well known' that the automorphism group of such a genus $g$ curve over an algebraically closed field is finite if and only if $g \ge 2$, this proves that $X \to B$ is quasi-finite. It is less clear to me why there is a $B' \to B$ with the required properties

Comment: Dear @user45878 thank you for your comment. Actually I need some even more basic reference because to me is not clear that $X_b=Aut(F_b)$, how do you prove that? If we are given that maybe we can avoid the fibers with infinite automorphsim group with the assumption that the fibers are quasi stable

Comment: I mean the fact alone that $Hom_B(F_b,X)=Isom_{F_b}(S\times_B F_b,S \times_B F_b)$ alone cannot prove $X_b=Aut(F_b)$. For instance take $X=S$.

Comment: Let $\eta \to B$ be the generic point of $B$ and let $S_{\eta}$ be the generic fibre of $f$, then per definition $X(\eta)=\operatorname{Aut}(S_{\eta})$

Comment: You have to be careful here because $X_b$ is a scheme and $\operatorname{Aut}(F_b)$ is a set. What is the precise thing that you are trying to prove?

Comment: And it might be helpful to know that $X \to S$ is generically étale (because $X_b$ is an étale scheme)